# How to pass POST data to an nginx location index default?

Tags: nginx, php

This is my nginx conf location block:

```
location /foo {
    alias /var/www/foo;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    location /foo/index.php {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

when I POST data to /foo it does not end up in index.php (the `$_POST` is empty).

I tried to find similar questions here but they all had rewrite rules or more complex setups.

How would I simply make nginx pass everything through to the default index?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you send data as POST (not GET)? Are you sure *this* index.php is interpreted?

Comment: Completely sure! If I explicitly POST (large files) to index.php directly everything works correctly!

Comment: There were 2 questions

Comment: Which index.php do you mean? Your config references two different ones. `/index.php` or `/foo/index.php` ?

Comment: @e2-e4 the second answer was pretty much obviously implied

Comment: @Michael Hampton /var/www/foo is the file system location, /foo is the nginx HTTP URL, the two are unrelated regarding the reference of index.php (it is a mapping)

Comment: ????? Hello ?????